# Whole website gives 404 because failed to open .htaccess and permission denied

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, cpanel

This what error looks like :

> - 2021-09-14 11:15:07.429580 [INFO] [3197404]
>   [176.232.56.158:62177:HTTP2-19#APVH_website.org:443] File not found
>   [/home/website/public_html/404.shtml]
> - 2021-09-14 11:15:07.429512 [INFO] [3197404] [176.232.56.158:62177:HTTP2-19#APVH_website.org:443] File not found
>   [/home/website/public_html/]
> - 2021-09-14 11:15:07.429380 [ERROR] [3197404] [HTAccess] Failed to open [/home/website/public_html/.htaccess]: Permission denied

My permission setting are 777 at this point. I've tried 644 and 664.

```
This is my .htaccess file :
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Dirs should be 755 and files 644. I suggest to contact your hosting company.

Comment: set permission / allow for WordPress root directory. like got to root directory and open terminal(ubuntu) and run sudo chmod -R 777 * on your local server and try again

Comment: `chmod -R 777 *` Don't. Even where there will be no attacks, it encourages negligence and invites mishaps.

Answer (score 1):

change the public_html folder permission to 755.